# Wordpress: Creating schedule

Tags: wordpress, events, schedule

I am trying to create a schedule to display AD. More specifically, I want to show one Ad from 12:00 AM to 06:00 AM & after that another add after. I am writing a plugin for that (even do not know if it possible by plugin or not) for the first time.

So far I have developed is this code:

```
function create_schedule()
{
    add_action('init','register_schedule');
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'create_schedule');

function destroy_schedule()
{
    remove_action('init','register_schedule');
}
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__,'destroy_schedule');


function register_schedule()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
    $month = date("n");
    $date = date("j");
    $year = date("Y");

    $hour = date("G");
    $minute = date("i");
    $second = date("s");

    if($hour >6 && $hour <= 23)
    {
        wp_schedule_single_event( mktime( 0,0,0,$month,$date+1,$year ), 'my_night_time_event');
    }
    if{
        wp_schedule_single_event( mktime( 0,0,0,$month,$date,$year ), 'my_day_time_event');
    }

}

function display_nightly_add()
{
}
add_action('my_night_time_event','display_nightly_add');


function display_daytime_add()
{
}
add_action('my_day_time_event','display_daytime_add');


function clear_schedules()
{
    $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'my_night_time_event' );
    wp_unschedule_event($timestamp, 'my_night_time_event' );

    $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'my_day_time_event' );
    wp_unschedule_event($timestamp, 'my_day_time_event' );
}
add_action('wp_logout','clear_schedules');
```

The problem is when one user logs in, the schedule is created and when the user logs out, the schedule is being cleared. I want to clear the schedule just for this user only, not other logged-in users. How I can implement it?

Can anyone put some light on this please?

Advance Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put `is_admin()` condition in your function...

Hope it works...